# Why Are Values not exporting from report - Access 2007

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, report

With regards to this Unsolved question:

[Application.ScreenUpdating in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609929/application-screenupdating-in-access)

I also noticed that when exporting to PDF or Excel the duration Values are not appearing (missing / blank(). Below please find my VBA code for the duration Values:

```vb
Private Sub Detail_Paint()

    Dim TestString As String

    TestString = Me.Duration1.Value

    Dim TestArray() As String

    TestArray = Split(TestString, ":")

    Dim Hours As String
    Dim Minutes As String
    Dim Seconds As String

    Dim HoursMinutes As Integer
    Dim MinutesMinutes As Integer
    Dim SecondsMinutes As Integer

    HoursMinutes = CInt(TestArray(0)) * 60
    MinutesMinutes = CInt(TestArray(1))
    SecondsMinutes = CInt(TestArray(2)) / 60

    Dim TimeInMinutes As Integer

    TimeInMinutes = HoursMinutes + MinutesMinutes + SecondsMinutes

    Me.Duration.Value = TimeInMinutes

End Sub
```

Any Ideas? If you have time please see the previous unresolved question! Thanks!

ADDED DETAILS:

The problem is that when exporting an exel or PDF file,the duration values are not appearing, due to the fact that duration is a String variable in VBA derived from another field in the database. I don't know why it is showing in report view but not in print preview

I Have also tried using the .ControlSource. In other words, I have tried using the code below. The problem with it now is that Access is Jamming as soon as I run it. I cannot Understand what is the problem with this code.

```
Private Sub Detail_Paint()


    Dim TestString As String


    TestString = Me.Duration1


    Dim TestArray() As String

    TestArray = Split(TestString, ":")


    Dim HoursMinutes As Integer
    Dim MinutesMinutes As Integer
    Dim SecondsMinutes As Integer

    HoursMinutes = CInt(TestArray(0)) * 60
    MinutesMinutes = CInt(TestArray(1))
    SecondsMinutes = CInt(TestArray(2)) / 60

    Dim TimeInMinutes As Integer

    TimeInMinutes = HoursMinutes + MinutesMinutes + SecondsMinutes

    Me.Duration.ControlSource = "=" & "'" & TimeInMinutes & "'"

End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application.ScreenUpdating in Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609929/application-screenupdating-in-access)

Comment: The error of that thread might be caused by what hoopzbarkley said in his reply, if that were the case I would reply to it myself, but this is a different matter

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to be altering the `.value` or `.text` properties of report elements at runtime because, as you (and I) discovered, it causes values to not display (if I remember correctly, I found that only the *last* value I set that way would display on the finished report).

What should work (assuming you've stepped through and verified that your variabes are being assigned as expected) is setting the `.ControlSource` property via something like

```
myObject.ControlSource = "=" & "'" & myString & "'"
```

With myObject and myString substituted. I'm guessing because `.value` and `.text` are re-evaluated before printing, but hopefully someone who actually knows what's going on can offer a proper explanation.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow Morning and let you know! Strange fact!

Comment: The problem now.. it's jamming.